Delete multiple copies of same ringtone on a Moto g stylus?
I have a Moto g stylus. I downloaded a ringtone Coal Miner's daughter. I tried to download another ringtone Ain't No grave. The code for the first song was a lot of letters and every time I tried to put the other ringtone in grave it kept duplicating the Coal Miner's daughter. Now I have like five copies in the list. How do I delete the copies of the coal miners daughter and have one copy in the list.

How did you download the ringtone? What did you mean by "the code"? Have you checked the 'Download" and "Ringtone" folders using file manager apps? Could you [edit] to add this information?
